# vhost rewrite sudomain to subfolder/file

Tags: apache

I've read countless examples but nothing quite like what I'm trying to do.

Is it possible to use a vhost to redirect traffic sent to a subdomain to a main domain/subfolder/file.html?

Example:

User types into their browser http://productname.example.net/. I'd like them to end up at https://example.net/category/productname.html

NOTE: The user may or may not enter httpS but the ending site is an SSL url.

My conf file is as follows:

```
<Directory C:/websites/productname.example.net>  
    #BestProduct.example.net
    #https://www.example.net/category/BestProduct/

    Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} bestproduct\.example\.net
    RewriteRule (.*) /category/bestProduct/$1 [L]   
</Directory>
```

The example.net has a different conf file because it is an SSL. I have a couple of websites running from the same server so I have several conf files.

My TLD DNS Entry: A Record is 123.456.789  (SSL URL)
My subdomain of BestPRoduct is 123.456.780 (non SSL URL) Is this correct? If I point this tot he SSL IP, the browser reports it as unsafe. The TLD redirects www.example.net to just example.net.

What do I need to change to make this scenario work as I've described? I'm stumped.

**UPDATE**
When I reviewed the access.log and the error.log file for the subdomain, it did not have any records in it (file size was 0 bytes). This makes me think that perhaps the DNS record is not setup correctly?

**FINAL UPDATE**
During the course of just a casual conversation with the client, I found out they want to do this with just about every product they sell (jaw drop). Apparently this client was informed by some SEO firm to setup subdomains for better SEO rankings. I recommended to the client to setup subfolders instead of subdomains and ultimately that is what we are doing. My argument was from a maintenance standpoint that setting up subdomains for every product wasn't feasible.

Comment: Just point the root folder of subdomain to a folder in main domain?

Comment: It needs to point to a particular product, not just a folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Q: *User types into their browser http://productname.example.net/. I'd like them to end up at https://example.net/category/productname.html*

A: Use [Redirect](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html). For example

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName productname.example.net
    DocumentRoot "C:/websites/productname.example.net"
    Redirect permanent "/" "https://example.net/category/productname.html"
</VirtualHost>
```

---

Notes

- To redirect *https* see [HOWTO: Apache Name-Based SSL-Enabled Virtual Hosting](http://archive.geekwisdom.com/dyn/node/215.html).

Comment: Well that was easy. :) Worked great!